# Get data from database based on 2 conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a database

```
CREATE TABLE `prod_sorteer` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL,
`idproduct` int(4) NOT NULL,
`groupid` int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And I want to get the idproducts form this table where groupid = 3 and = 5

I understand that this does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM `prod_sorteer` WHERE `prod_sorteer.groupid`='3' AND `prod_sorteer.groupid`='5'
```

But what is the right way to do this?

The complete query is going tobe something like this:

```
Select producten.idproduct AS id, producten.productlink, producten.prijs, prod_omschrijving.producttitel, prod_categorie.idcategorieen, merk.merknaam 
FROM producten 
INNER JOIN prod_omschrijving ON producten.idproduct=prod_omschrijving.idproduct 
INNER JOIN prod_categorie ON producten.idproduct=prod_categorie.idproduct    
INNER JOIN merk ON producten.idmerk=merk.idmerk 
INNER JOIN prod_sorteer ON prod_sorteer.idproduct=producten.idproduct    
WHERE prod_omschrijving.taal='NL' 
AND producten.verhuurlijst='1' 
AND aantal >=0 
AND prod_categorie.idcategorieen='5024' 
AND prod_sorteer.groupid='3' 
AND prod_sorteer.groupid='5' 
GROUP BY prod_sorteer.idproduct 
ORDER BY prod_omschrijving.producttitel 
LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0
```

edit:
I need both conditions (groupid) to be true.
Like I want to select all the products who have groupid 3 and groupid 5.
With OR I select al the products who have groupid 3 or groupid 5

Comment: The conditions are conflicting, why not run two queries instead?

Comment: how can one value in a table be both 3 and 5?

Comment: the idea is that i want to show all the products who have groupid 3 and groupid 5

Comment: OR not AND ..boolean logic: http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/235-logic-logic-everything-is-logic.html

Comment: I read the informatio and I understand the theory, but based on this theary I realy need AND and not OR

Comment: No, you need OR [so you don't understand the theory].

Comment: i quess so... Doesn't change the fact that OR is not giving me the result I want.